# how to check whether services is running on 32 or 64 bit mode

Tags: web-services

I am using windows sever 2003 and it is 64 bit server, however there are some application whose services are running on 32 bit mode, I just want to check which are ther services are running on 32bit mode.

Is there any command in windows or there is any settings to find out this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the task manager, 32 bit processes have `*32` appended to their name in the processes list.